# A question about modal verb "can"

Tags: modal-verbs

> The World Wide Web is sometimes jokingly called the World Wide Wait because it **can** be very slow.
>
> Peter **can** be really difficult at times even though he’s a nice person in general.

I think in the above examples, the modal verb "can" is used to express "**general possibility or theotrical possibility**" rather than "**ability**". Am I right?

Comment: We use **can** to mean _sometimes_. People **can do** funny things when they've experienced something terrible. (= people sometimes do funny things)

Answer (score 3):

With animate subjects the line between possibility and ability is hard to draw, because ability implies possibility.

Since Peter has the ability to do or be X, then X is possible.

With inanimate subjects, possibility unusually comes to the fore: *Appearances can be deceptive.*

When we speak of possibility as habitual, we can paraphrase with *sometimes*.

*Flash floods can be dangerous.*

*Flash floods are dangerous sometimes.*

Thus the natural usage of *at times* (= *sometimes*) with regard to *Peter can be really difficult.*

*Peter is really difficult at times (=sometimes)*.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any real distinction between ability and possibility in these cases. Either way you interpret **can**, the sentences are true.

English modal verbs are sloppy. Each serves many different purposes and meanings, sometimes simultaneously. They lack the precision to make such a fine distinction. When you need to make a distinction like that clearly, you must add some extra words to the sentence to spell it out precisely.

You can* see the same ambiguity in **will**. The older, primary meaning of **will** expresses mental determination or choice in the present tense: "Do as you will." **Will** also, much more commonly today, just indicates the future tense: "What will happen tomorrow?" So, which meaning is intended in the following sentence?

> I ***will*** win!

You could understand it as expressing the speaker's present mental determination to win, or you could understand it as stating a prediction that the speaker will win. Really, though, the verb doesn't distinguish. The speaker sort of means both, and a listener sort of hears both.

---

<sup>* Now that does that **can** mean possibility or ability? Hmm, mostly ability, but, uh…</sup>